# Why does my Python script fail with syntax errors?

Tags: command-line, python

While running the simple Python program below, I'm getting the following error:

```
./url_test.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('                  
./url_test.py: line 2: `response = urllib2.urlopen('http://python.org/')'
```

---

```
import urllib2      
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://python.org/')  
print "Response:", response

# Get the URL. This gets the real URL. 
print "The URL is: ", response.geturl()

# Getting the code
print "This gets the code: ", response.code

# Get the Headers. 
# This returns a dictionary-like object that describes the page fetched, 
# particularly the headers sent by the server
print "The Headers are: ", response.info()

# Get the date part of the header
print "The Date is: ", response.info()['date']

# Get the server part of the header
print "The Server is: ", response.info()['server']

# Get all data
html = response.read()
print "Get all data: ", html

# Get only the length
print "Get the length :", len(html)

# Showing that the file object is iterable
for line in response:
 print line.rstrip()

# Note that the rstrip strips the trailing newlines and carriage returns before
# printing the output.
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted your script and it isn't giving me any errors! Are you sure about the syntax errors? Which version of python are you using? Also, I think this has nothing directly to do with ubuntu, has it? Chances are moderators might delete it!

Comment: I'm using python 2.6....

Comment: Just try double quotes around the url and see if anything happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You missed to add a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the beginning  of the script to tell the shell to interpret your script as a python script. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

or:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

See also: [Why do people write #!/usr/bin/env python on the first line of a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script)

Answer (score 9):

Those errors are not typical Python tracebacks. Those errors look like shell errors.

I think you are trying to run a Python script with Bash (or an another shell), i.e. you are doing something like:

```
bash url_test.py
```

Instead, you should use:

```
python url_test.py
```